# Need data to access localized weather data

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, weather

I am trying to build an application similar to zyGrib where in I want to add wind data onto an open layers map for a small local area. 
I am aware that there are public sources that I can access to get this data but I haven't been successful in finding one though. 
I want to preferably be able to access a very localized data set instead of downloading a huge global data set.

Comment: Your question sounds ambiguous. On the one hand you talk about an API, on the other hand about zipped files for download. Which is it? Does your data have to be 'live'? Explain what *similar to zyGrib* is - don't make us have to look that up. Please [edit] your question. [This will help](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: Did you [search this site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+weather+api)?

Comment: When you use a chosen API, you can filter the data you want to get based on location. You don't have to download all the data.

Answer (score 1):

The Wunderground API

https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

has features for selecting a region. This can be used to get current
conditions for a particular locale, including surface winds.